# Getting data from partials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a main model that contains 3 objects that each line up to a partial view.  The model is passed into a form that has 4 partials which each of the partials has part of the model passed into. When my form submits (from the main view, not the partials) I am not getting an data from the partials in the controller.  Is there something I am missing?  It seems I can send data from the model to the partials, have trouble getting it back on the form submit.

```
Main View  
@model  
@Html.BeginForm  
{  
->Partial1(model.section1)  
->Partial2(model.section2)  
->Partial3(model.section3)  
->Partial4(model.section4)  
submit button  
}
```

I can post more info if I didn't explain something very well.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: do you by any chance have any nested forms?

Comment: can you show one of your partial views

Comment: No, The only form I have is in the main view and it surrounds all 4 partials.

Comment: @TylerSmith - I don't have a clue but did you try to debug this using Fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with is EditorTemplates.  These allowed me to get the info from the sectioned out bits of the form.

Comment: So you don't use partials and put the entire html in the form using your templates?

Comment: No, I put the partials in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates then I called it as a EditorFor(model) where model is the same name as the editor template and it just works. That way I didnt have to have my whole form in one file like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If your partials are collections see http://nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem